# Can I automatically break CSS columns into 'pages' that fit vertically inside the viewport?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a page that presents a long article for comfortable reading. I would like to break the text into columns on wide screens, but I don't want to make users scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and then back up to the top again after finishing each column.

Is there a way, without using JavaScript, to automatically split the article into vertical sections ('pages') that are short enough to fit entirely within the viewport? Here's some ASCII art to illustrate:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       === Some Title ===                    |
|                                                             |
| You think water moves fast?    it out. Now we took an oath, |
| You should see ice. It moves   that I'm breaking now. We    |
| like it has a mind. Like it    said we'd say it was the     |
| knows it killed the world      snow that killed the other   |
| once and got a taste for       two, but it wasn't. Nature   |
| murder. After the avalanche,   is lethal but it doesn't     |
| it took us a week to climb     hold a candle to man.        |
| out. Now, I don't know                                      |
| exactly when we turned on      Like you, I used to think    |
| each other, but I know that    the world was this great     |
| seven of us survived the       place where everybody lived  |
| slide... and only five made    by the same standards I did, |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| then some kid with a nail     Dr. Wu inserted a gene that   |
| showed me I was living in     makes a single faulty enzyme  |
| his world, a world where      in protein metabolism. The    |
| chaos rules not order, a      animals can't manufacture the |
| world where righteousness is  amino acid lysine. Unless     |
| not rewarded. That's Cesar's  they're continually supplied  |
| world, and if you're not      with lysine by us, they'll    |
| willing to play by his rules, slip into a coma and die.     |
| then you're gonna have to pay                               |
| the price.                    Do you see any Teletubbies in |
| The lysine contingency -      here? Do you see a slender    |
| it's intended to prevent the  plastic tag clipped to my     |
| spread of the animals is case shirt with my name printed on |
| they ever got off the island. it?                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The lines represent the height of the viewport. The columns end at the bottom of the viewport and the text flows to the top of the next column, which begins at the top of the viewport. Once that 'page' of text has been read, the user scrolls down to the next one and begins again. This allows the text to be split into columns without requiring lots of extra scrolling. On a large screen, the 'pages' would be tall, but on a small screen they would be short enough to fit within the viewport.

A good solution doesn't have to be perfectly semantic, but shouldn't require any JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

I played a bit around. It just works with plain text, but is responsive.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fitcol = function(options) {

            changes = function(el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                            settings = $.extend({
                            intendedheight: $(window).height() - ($el.outerHeight()-$el.height()), // set default intended height (rough estimation: height of window - padding and border)
                    }, options),
                            height = $el.height(),
                            ratio = height / settings.intendedheight,
                            text = $el.text(), //clear all inner html (should be fixed) currently needed in case of window resize
                            length = text.length,
                            intendedlength = Math.floor(length / ratio),
                            i = 1,
                            html = '</div><div class="column">'; //code for a breakpoint
                            text = '<div class="column">' + text;
                var correction = 20; 
                while((intendedlength * i) + correction < text.length) { // loop to put breakpoints into the text
                    var j = 0
                    while(text.charAt((intendedlength * i) + correction) !== ' ' &&  j<= 20) { //loop so we don't break words
                                correction--;
                                j++;
                                }
                    text = text.substr(0, (intendedlength * i) + correction ) + html + text.substr((intendedlength * i) + correction);
                    correction += html.length; // we are changing the length of text when we add html
                    i++;
                }
                text = text + '</div>';

                $el.removeClass('column');
                $el.html(text);

            };
            //make it responsive
            return this.each(function() {
                    var that = this;
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                            changes(that);
                    });
                    changes(this);
            });
    };
}(jQuery));

$('.container').fitcol();
```

See it at http://codepen.io/wudi96/pen/doXYrv

It's very experimental and far from beeing optimized.

Would be nice to use together with panelSnap http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/.

Comment: This does use JavaScript, but it does what one would expect, like a book or magazine. Should be made part of css flex.

Answer (score 1):

You want css columns and you just need to put the text into different divs in groups. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PEE6G/) is a jsfiddle that shows it. Here is my css:

```
.mydiv
{
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:2;
}
```

Comment: How would this automatically respond to the size of the viewport? Doesn't this split things up based on how the text is split among the divs rather than the size of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think that http://quirksmode.org/css/columns/ is what you are looking for.

See Example: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model

Comment: I know about the CSS columns module; what I'm wondering is specifically how to break columns so that they fit vertically in the viewport. Can you point me towards how to do that in particular?

Comment: I think your best bet there is just to make an educated guess... call it every 1000 words or whatever. Underestimate. Then put a nice break between the pages, and it's okay if the page isn't quite to the bottom of the viewport. Javascript is probably the  only way to do this perfectly

Comment: With some display table, height:100% and column-width to 50%; you sould be able to handle that, no ? Or maybe: height:100vh; (vh unit is according to viewport height) http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: @matty-d Thanks, that's a fair suggestion. Definitely a reasonable option of there isn't an automatic alternative.

Comment: @dievardump I don't think so; the divs can't just be sized with CSS because where the tags appear in the markup is what determines where the columns break.

Comment: @Nathan and with the vh unit ? vw works fine on mobile, I'm not sure for vh

Comment: @dievardump Sizing with CSS won't do anything AFAIK; how big the element is on screen doesn't affect where the column break occurs. It appears that that has to be done in the markup itself.

Comment: Recommendations (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#pagination-and-overflow-outside-multicol last example) says that using `break-after:column;` when there is a height or a max-height on the element should add new columns after. This *should* (but sadly don't) work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ioBDa

Answer (score -2):

Honestly, I think the best answer to this one is to avoid pagination altogether. People are quite used to reading single column blogs, news stories, articles etc. I'd just set `max-width:800px; width:95%; margin:0 auto;` and have it as one long stream.

This might cause issues if you have loads of images, but can be solved by only loading those that are needed, see [lazy loading](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/).

That's a personal opinion. Remember pages can be as long as you like, pagination is for books ;)

Good luck.

Comment: There is a reason newspapers and magazines use columns: makes an article easier to read. But on a screen in particular, it is easier to read an entire screenful of text (a page) before needing to scroll. If you have to scroll down a long column to get to the next column, you're working too hard, even if the website provides a "scroll back to the top" button at the end of each column. Horizontal scrolling of the paged columns works nicely and the css can be done, but users don't expect ever to scroll text horizontally.